# Problems using Struct.new() into a Rails 3.2.3 MongoID model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I've a mongoid model and method like the following :

```
class Category
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  ...

  def self.custom_find
    ...
    Str = Struct.new(:arg1, :arg2)
    array << Str.new(one, two)
    ...
  end
end
```

and I get the following error :

```
dynamic constant assignment (SyntaxError)
    Str = Struct.new(:arg1, :arg2)
```

I tried moving `Str = Struct.new(:arg1, :arg2)` into config/initializers/categories.rb but then I get :

```
BSON::InvalidDocument in TrendsController#index

Cannot serialize an object of class Category into BSON.
```

by removing the custom_find offending method, everithing else works fine, then I guess is something related to `"Struct"`.

Any idea ?

Comment: A Struct is a convenient way to bundle a number of attributes together, using accessor methods, without having to write an explicit class in Ruby (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Struct.html)

Comment: Found that already. Should have googled before commenting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around dynamic constant assignment error in several ways:

```
array = Struct.new(:arg1, :arg2).new(one, two)
```

or

```
Object.const_set :Str, Struct.new(:arg1, :arg2)
Str # => Str
```

This shouldn't solve serialization problem, though.